# Problem with PCB making

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, etching

I have followed a process to make a PCB, whose link is given below. I have followed the every process as mentioned with correct proportion of chemicals. But, unfortunately, this didn't work (traces were not stick to the copper board). I have used glossy paper in this experiment. What could be the possible reason of my failure Or this process is a invalid process ?

[LINK](https://www.instructables.com/id/Heatless-cold-Toner-Transfer-for-PCB-Making/)

Comment: I've never used that method, so just guessing.  The instructable seems to be using plain paper.  It looks plain, and there's no mention of glossy paper or other special paper.  Try it with plain paper.  If it works, write it up as an answer.  Also include more details of the process (toner transfer, cold chemical process, etc.) in the question.

Comment: ok. I will try do more experiment on it.

Comment: You can have professionally made PCB for probably less than the cost of your supplies and chemicals though. https://jlcpcb.com/ 2$ for 2 layer pcb.

Comment: @Damien:  Maybe, maybe not.  A typical double sided board runs me about 40€ if I have it made as a prototype board with no solder mask or silkscreen layers and I can wait a week for it.  I can make a single sided board at home for far less, and have it done in a few hours. I usually have a board made because I'd rather spend that Saturday afternoon doing more interesting things than etching boards.  But, if I find I need a small circuit while fiddling around, I might make it so that I can get on with an experiment rather than waiting a week.

Comment: @JRE You can get double side board for a few $ delivered in 2-3 days. Not sure it worth the time and money without talking to deal with dangerous chemicals. How do you do via in your homemade boards?

Comment: @Damien:  I'm in Germany so delivery is a bit different than for whatever manufacturer you are using.  I have mine made by Eurocircuits (a German company) so there's never trouble with shipping or high delivery costs.  I do hand made boards single side only, and only for SMD parts.  I can make those in an afternoon using the toner transfer method.

Comment: https://www.seeedstudio.io ships to germany within 4 days for 4$

Comment: @Damien Any idea on the above mentioned process? Because for testing purpose, we have to make some prototype. After experiment, we can make 2 layer board for final production.

Comment: @AakashDey I'm with Damien, getting prototype PCBs made by JLCPCB is cheaper than the chemicals and materials alone. Plus they include soldermask, silkscreen, etc. MUCH better options than making your own PCBs.